# bash shell doesn't appear when terminal is launched

Tags: terminal, osx

Whenever I launch terminal in my Macbook Pro. The terminal doesn't show command line of bash shell. What appears is the command line of Mathematica 9.0. It has been long time after installing the Mathematica and I suffered for this issue so long. Could you please suggest possible solutions?

Comment: Are you using Mac OS X?

Comment: yes. I use El Capitan.

Answer (score 4):

You can set your shell to bash using

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

This should work on most Unix-like systems. On OS X, it may or may not work, though, due to its use of Open Directory. In that case running chsh without any parameters and setting the shell interactively might work. You need to re-login after this change.

If that still doesn't change your shell, then you may need to change the UserShell entry in the Directory Service database as described in this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/163921

EDIT: you can change the shell command from "Login shell" to "/bin/bash" temporarily in your iTerm settings. Do that in order to run chsh or dscl as described above.